# Show Notes & Attachments on Custom Object in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, page-layout, attachment

Does anyone know how to show Notes & Attachments associated with a custom object in Lightning?

I have an Insurance Claim object.  I have created a custom page in Setup > Lightning App Builder > Insurance Claim > Edit.

The page is a Header and Right Sidebar layout.  In the header I have a Highlights Panel, in the left pane I have Tabs (Record Details, Related List Quick Links), and in the right panel I have Activities component.

I'd like to have a list of Notes and Attachments show up in the right panel.  But, I have no idea what compnent to drop in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Related List - Single component, and choose the Notes & Attachments related list. Note that the list must be available in the page layout, or it won't appear.

Comment: Aren't only Files and New Notes available in Lightning?

Comment: @Oleksiy That's what I thought, too, but I double-checked, it's in my (developer) org.